# How to know which Thread has finished first

Tags: java

I have created these two threads  ( in other clases i have given them atributtes not important for my question)

I want to know how do i know which thread has finished first

```
public class Race {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Thread th1 = new Thread(new Dog("Bubu",2));
            Thread th2 = new Thread(new Rabbit("Lepri",3));
            th1.start();
            th2.start();

        } catch (GaraException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Gara.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I want to know how do i know which thread has finished first*" You should first wait until both threads have finished. Otherwise, your main application might terminate before either of those threads finished. Furthermore, if you want to make any performance measurement (or fair races), you should guarantee that both threads start at the same time, e.g. through a `CountDownLatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without busy looping or starting a thread for each thread to join on:

```
        AtomicReference<Thread> first = new AtomicReference<>();

        Dog bubu = new Dog("Bubu",2);
        Thread th1 = new Thread(() -> {
            bubu.run();
            first.compareAndSet(null, Thread.currentThread());
        }, "Bubu");

        Rabbit lepri = new Rabbit("Lepri",3);
        Thread th2 = new Thread(() -> {
            lepri.run();
            first.compareAndSet(null, Thread.currentThread());
        }, "Lepri");

        th1.start();
        th2.start();
        th1.join();
        th2.join();

        System.err.println("First: "+first);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java code run from top to bottom, if you have already run the program and it ran successfully, it means that thread th1 will finish first before thread th2 (from top to bottom).

Comment: This is not how threads work. Threads introduce concurrency, thus the code does not necessarily run from top to bottom.